# Calculate voltage over resistor

Tags: basic

I have a problem when calculating voltage over resistor because one method worked for one problem but not the next.

[image: Fist problem]

[image: Second problem]

I solved (b) like this:

$$12-4=8V$$
$$8*\frac{60}{60+20}=6V$$
$$V2 = 6V+4V=10V$$
and that was correct according to the solution manual. I solve (c) like this:

$$-14-(-2)=-12V$$
$$-12*\frac{60}{30+60}=-8V$$
$$V2 = -8V+-2V=-10V$$
And this is wrong. It should be -8V. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: look closer. In the first example, V2 is the potential at the given point (referenced to some common ground not shown in the schematic). Whereas on the second example, V3 is the potential difference between the two points shown by the arrow. Your computation is correct, but you're not actually calculating the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by the same equation.

Assume Va, Vb and Vc are the voltages at the nodes shown in the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ARkK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then you have:

$$
V_c - V_b = \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \cdot (V_a - V_b)
$$

Rearrange as you see fit and plug-in your numbers to see that it works in both cases (and be careful when handling the sign of the voltages).

Note that in your last case, \$V_c - V_b\$ is to be identified with \$V_3\$, whereas in your first case \$V_2\$ is the same as \$V_c\$.

Comment: $$V_c=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}(V_a-V_b)+V_b$$ and I still get Vc as -10V

Comment: I asked my teacher and according to him, you only subtract -2v in the end if you are measuring towards ground as you are in example 1 but in the second one we are messing over the resistor only and therefore we do not need to subtract -2. Is this correct?

Comment: Look closely at your pictures: V2 is not the voltage of point C referenced to ground (my Vc), but the voltage *across* R2. So, as I said in my answer, V3 is to be identified with Vc-Vb in my formula. You must not bring Vb to second member.